# Could not able to import external Javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm kind of new to javascript programming,
I am trying to build a basic image slideshow using a plugin called Cycle (jQuery plugin), I am trying to import this plugin to my code, but for some reason it doesn't work, I've included the jQuery library and it works just fine

This is the HTML (+ jQuery in the `<head>` tag):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="he">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <script src="scriptCycle.js"></script> /* This line doesn't work */
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#slideshow").css("overflow", "hidden"); /* This line works just fine */

            $("ul#slides").cycle({ /* This is from the Cycle plugin (scriptCycle.js) - doesn't work */
                fx: "fade",
                pause: 1,
                prev: "#prev",
                next: "#next"
            });

            $("#slideshow").hover(function() { /* This line works just fine */
                $("ul#nav").fadeIn();
            },

            function() {
                $("ul#nav").fadeOut();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="slideshow">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li id="prev"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
                <li id="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="slides">
                <li><img src="1.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="2.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="3.jpg"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS (style.css):

```
body, h1, ul, li {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
}

body {
    background: #FFF
}

#container {
    width: 1095px; margin: 40px;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow {
    width: 800px; height: 400px; padding: 15px 0 0 12px;
    background: #FFF;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: relative; z-index: 5;
}

div#slideshow ul#nav {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute; top: 210px;
}
div#slideshow ul#nav li#prev {
    position: absolute;
    left:30px;
}

div#slideshow ul#nav li#next {
    position: absolute;
    left:740px;
}

div#slideshow ul#nav li a {
    display: block; width: 24px; height: 35px; text-indent: -9999px;
}

div#slideshow ul#nav li#prev a {
    background:url(leftArrow.png);
}

div#slideshow ul#nav li#next a {
    background:url(rightArrow.png);
}

div#slideshow ul#slides {
    list-style: none;
}

div#slideshow ul#slides li {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

There is 0 room for error with the file path, they can be found alongside one another in the same directory,
What am I missing here guys?

Comment: I think `<script src="scriptCycle.js"></script>` might have to come AFTER the line that loads `jquery.min.js`, since you said it is a plugin for it. It's probably erring out.

Comment: For the future, you have to understand that, in Javascript you have to arrange linking external script files according to the dependency. In other words, the file that depend on another file, it must come after it in order.

Answer (score 2):

Put `<script src="scriptCycle.js"></script>` AFTER the line that loads `jquery.min.js`, since you said it is a plugin for it. It's probably erring out.

Comment: that seems to do the trick, but now my hover function isn't working, it's working fine if I comment the Cycle function out

Comment: I think that warrants a NEW stackoverflow question. ;)

Comment: I would do that but stackoverflow wants me to wait 3 days XD

Answer (score 0):

jquery should be placed before your custom script all scripts added to your index will work in order from top to bottom so its always calls the library you are trying to initiate first.

just change it to this below:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scriptCycle.js"></script>
```